# How to Set-up PHP Spatie Crawler - Outputting Results

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm trying to set up [Spatie, a PHP crawler](https://github.com/spatie/crawler), but am having a hard time interpreting the documentation. The code seems pretty robust, but the documentation seems to have some very basic gaps by lacking a clear path to 'this is how to get a working example without making too many assumptions'.

That said, I've been reading a bunch of other GitHub threads & articles to try to get things at least 'closer' to getting set-up.

What I've done

- I've finally got things to the point where I'm not getting any errors
  resulting from un-imported classes, etc

Where I'm stuck

- Now that I have some code in place, it's unclear to me what actually happens, which I know sounds odd
- What I would expect is some kind of 1) loop 2) way to output URLs as they crawl 3) a way to output the results
- Specifically, as a use case, I want to have a list of URLs & their respective status codes

Any insights with respect to what I'm missing would be massively appreciated.

My code:

```
use Spatie\Crawler\Crawler;
use Spatie\Crawler\CrawlObservers;
use Spatie\Crawler\CrawlObservers\CrawlObserver; // I had to specify this namespace, without it I kept getting an Exception: Class 'CrawlObserver' not found error
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface; // If I don't set this, I get an error: " Could not check compatibility between myClassExtendingCrawlObserver..."

class myClassExtendingCrawlObserver extends CrawlObserver {
    /**
     * Called when the crawler will crawl the url.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface $url
     */
    public function willCrawl(UriInterface $url)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Called when the crawler has crawled the given url successfully.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface $url
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface|null $foundOnUrl
     */
    public function crawled(
        UriInterface $url,
        ResponseInterface $response,
        ?UriInterface $foundOnUrl = null
    ){

    }

    /**
     * Called when the crawler had a problem crawling the given url.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface $url
     * @param \GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $requestException
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface|null $foundOnUrl
     */
    public function crawlFailed(
        UriInterface $url,
        RequestException $requestException,
        ?UriInterface $foundOnUrl = null
    ){
      
    }

    /**
     * Called when the crawl has ended.
     */
    public function finishedCrawling()
    {
    }
}

if(!class_exists('Spatie\\Crawler\\CrawlObservers\\CrawlObserver')){ // I was using this to check what to include
  $myClassExtendingCrawlObserver = new myClassExtendingCrawlObserver();
  $url = 'https://www.example.com';
  try {
    Crawler::create()
    ->setCrawlObserver($myClassExtendingCrawlObserver)
    ->startCrawling($url);
  } catch (exception $e) {
    error_log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spatie Crawler loops over links found in URL, and return status and other information.
Here is how you can get more information:

```
public function crawled(
    UriInterface      $url,
    ResponseInterface $response,
    ?UriInterface     $foundOnUrl = null
): void
{
    echo 'Crawling URL: ' . urldecode($url) . ' ... ' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Crawl result: ' . $response->getStatusCode() . ' - ' . $response->getReasonPhrase() . PHP_EOL;
    if (isset($response->getHeaders()['Server'])) {
        echo 'Server: ' . $response->getHeaders()['Server'][0] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (isset($response->getHeaders()['Set-Cookie'])) {
        // You can use loop here
        echo 'Cookies: ' . $response->getHeaders()['Set-Cookie'][0] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 301 || $response->getStatusCode() == 302) {
        echo $response->getHeaders()['Location'][0] . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Redirect: " . rtrim($url, '/') . $response->getHeaders()['Location'][0] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

You can handle failed requests here:

```
public function crawlFailed(
    UriInterface     $url,
    RequestException $requestException,
    ?UriInterface    $foundOnUrl = null
): void
{
    echo '!!! Crawl Failed !!! : ' . $url . PHP_EOL;
}
```